# A simple way to add smoother transition between background images that change after specified time?

Tags: javascript, image, background, transition, fade

I have my JavaScript set up so that the background image in div#hero alternates between 3 different images every 5000 milliseconds.

Two problems:

1. How do I add a smooth fade transition as it changes images?
2. The first 5000 milliseconds before the function begins, no image displays. What is the simplest way to display the first image without waiting the time interval, and then proceed to go by the interval time after the original page load?

   ```
   var interval_time = 5000;//in milliseconds
   setInterval(carousel, interval_time);
   function carousel(){
   var imgCount = 3;
       var dir = 'images/';
       var randomCount = Math.round(Math.random() * (imgCount - 1)) + 1;
       var images = new Array
               images[1] = "1.jpg",
               images[2] = "2.jpg",
               images[3] = "3.jpg",
       document.getElementById("hero").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + dir +              images[randomCount] + ")";
   }
   ```

Comment: That's not even valid JavaScript. I'd recommend using CSS for the transitions.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options. I would suggest something like this:

```
var interval_time = 5000;//in milliseconds
function carousel(){
    var imgCount = 3;
    var dir = 'images/';
    var randomCount = Math.round(Math.random() * (imgCount - 1)) + 1;
    var images = ["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg"];
    document.getElementById("hero").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + dir + images[randomCount] + ")";
    setInterval(carousel(), interval_time);
};
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   carousel();
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: that solves the problem of no image displaying the first 5000 milliseconds (thanks!) but it doesn't automatically alternate the images anymore, nor does it include a fade transition (?)